# Handling global varibales when using AMD Requirejs + Backbonejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

As in the application I need to have some configured variables which are to be global and I am using them across modules. 
My config file may look like.

**config.js**:

```
var config = {
    baseServiceUrl: 'http://localhost/baseServiceUrl',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost/baseUrl',

    mapping_764: {
            location:'Austin',
            emailAddress:'austin@customerservice.com', 
            registerLink:'https://www.customercare.com/en/austin/registration/',
            fbLikeLink:'https://www.facebook.com/customercare.austin',
            microSite: 'http://austin.customercare.com/'
        }
}
```

I am just loading this file using script tag along with requirejs.
    `<script src="js/app/config.js"></script>`
    `<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>`
Now the global variable(object) **config** can be used in all the modules and also from browser console. So I was thinking what if someone changes this config attributes, the application is definitely going to crash because this config variable is used for service calls and for many other things.

Is there any way to handle this kind of issues.?

Answer (score 5):

A couple things may help you:

First, for the pure "site configuration" (e.g. REST URLs) info, RequireJS has a configuration API. From [the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig):

```
requirejs.config({
    config: {
        'bar': {
            size: 'large'
        },
        'baz': {
            color: 'blue'
        }
    }
});

//bar.js, which uses simplified CJS wrapping:
//http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    //Will be the value 'large'
    var size = module.config().size;
});
```

There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608685/using-requirejs-how-do-i-pass-in-global-objects-or-singletons-around) which addresses the general case of passing global variables around if you don't want to use the config API.

Second, for bootstrapping data into Backbone models, there is extensive discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js)