# RequireJS: Config parameters not being passed into package

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dependency-management

I'm trying to send configuration parameters into my package's main.js file and it doesn't seem to be working.  What am I doing wrong?  Here's the files and path information

**/config.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : '../src',
    config : {
        'AAM' : {
            get : null,
            set : null
        }
    },
    packages : [ 'AAM']
});
```

**/src/AAM/main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        AAMAsPermission : 'AAM/perms/asPermission'
    }
});

// Start the main app logic.
requirejs(['AAMAsPermission'], function(AAMAsPermission) {

});
```

**/src/AAM/perms/asPermission**

```
define(['module'], function(module) {
    module.config() // empty object.  Why?
    ....
});
```

In /src/AAM/perms/asPermission, the object returned from module.config() is empty.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig):

> For passing config to a package, target the main module in the package, not the package ID:

So you should configure it like this:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : '../src',
    config : {
        // target the module, not the package
        'AAM/perms/asPermission' : {
            get : null,
            set : null
        }
    },
    packages : [ 'AAM']
});
```

If that doesn't meet your needs, you might also try a separate global module for holding the singleton: [Using RequireJS, how do I pass in global objects or singletons around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608685/using-requirejs-how-do-i-pass-in-global-objects-or-singletons-around)